# Can't change background color in <option>

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When I put `onClick` into `<select>`, script work, but When I put it into  `option` it's not working!

Here is HTML `select` script:

```
            <select name="<?php echo $pos; ?>" id="<?php echo $pos; ?>">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option onClick="ship('1','<?php echo $pos; ?>');" value="1">1</option>
                <option onClick="ship('2','<?php echo $pos; ?>');" value="2">2</option>
                <option onClick="ship('3','<?php echo $pos; ?>');" value="3">3</option>
                <option onClick="ship('4','<?php echo $pos; ?>');" value="4">4</option>
            </select>
```

And here is JavaScript:

```
<script>
    function ship(num, pos) {
        if (num == 0){
            document.getElementById(pos).style.backgroundColor="white";
        }
        if (num == 1){
            document.getElementById(pos).style.backgroundColor="red";
        }
        if (num == 2){
            document.getElementById(pos).style.backgroundColor="green";
        }
        if (num == 3){
            document.getElementById(pos).style.backgroundColor="blue";
        }
        if (num == 4){
            document.getElementById(pos).style.backgroundColor="yellow";
        }



    }

</script>
```

Comment: You've given the `select` an ID, but calling `ship()` on the options which don't have an `ID`.

Comment: But I want to change select color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onclick` on an option doesn't work on most browsers (or probably none of them), Instead you can just listen to the change event of the select and switch based on its `value` property.

You could just do:

```
var color = [
    "white",
    "red",
    "green",
    "blue",
    "yellow"];

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('selectId').onchange = function () {
        this.style.backgroundColor = color[this.value];
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4uy5f/)**

Comment: @TomášAresakMalčánek added a demo as well.

Comment: I don't know why, but it's not working.. Is it jQuery script?

Comment: @TomášAresakMalčánek I am not using any jquery... remove onclick from your select. Would you be able to know id in advance...? How does your php code now looks like. You need to replace `selectId` with actual id of your select element.

Comment: @TomášAresakMalčánek I am not too familiar with php but one thing is you should remove `onChange="ship();"` Because you are biding the change handler with the code already inside the window.onload. Do you see any errors in your console and how does your rendered html look like?

Comment: @TomášAresakMalčánek You should check your rendered code (view source) and look at the console if there are any errors on it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43067/discussion-between-tomas-aresak-malcanek-and-psl)

Answer (score 0):

For an option onClick may not work sometime. so better to place onChange function in select tag and also pass value of selected child .

Answer (score 0):

You should use the onChange event on the select element like:

```
<select onChange="ship(this.selectedIndex, this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
```

In this case the ship function gets the index and the value of the selected option. So in your case changing the options to

```
 <option value="<?php echo $pos; ?>">1</option>
```

might be needed, too.
Edit: only got half the question. See PSLs answer for a better solution :)